# Update multiple substrings within a string

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a single text string stored in a SQL table which contains all of the text below. The format is XML but the field definition is varchar.

I am using SQL Server 2012 to query this data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  
    <SaveFileContext xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    
            <Mappings>  
                  <SaveFileModel Header="Model1" FullPath="Model1" ViewType="ModelView" /> 
   
                  <SaveFileModel Header="xyz" FullPath="\\server\directory\" ViewType="TradeView" />      

                  <SaveFileModel Header="Model2" FullPath="Model2" ViewType="ModelView" />

                  <SaveFileModel Header="Model3" FullPath="Model3" ViewType="ModelView" /> 

                  <SaveFileModel Header="abc" FullPath="\\server\directory\" ViewType="TradeView" />    

                  <SaveFileModel Header="def" FullPath="\\server\directory\" ViewType="TradeView" />

                  <SaveFileModel Header="ghi" FullPath="\\server\directory\" ViewType="TradeView"/>
            </Mappings>  
    </SaveFileContext>
```

How can I update or remove the entire lines of text where viewtype="ModelView"?

I want to remove any lines where viewtype="ModelView" within this single string and replace it with a blank space. In the example above I want to remove 3 lines total and leave the rest.

In the end I want the string to look like below (keep in mind all lines are contained in 1 single string. I just separated them to make viewing them easier.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  
    <SaveFileContext xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    
            <Mappings>  
                  <SaveFileModel Header="xyz" FullPath="\\server\directory\" ViewType="TradeView" />      

                  <SaveFileModel Header="abc" FullPath="\\server\directory\" ViewType="TradeView" />    

                  <SaveFileModel Header="def" FullPath="\\server\directory\" ViewType="TradeView" />

                  <SaveFileModel Header="ghi" FullPath="\\server\directory\" ViewType="TradeView"/>
            </Mappings>  
    </SaveFileContext>
```

This is my current query that I am using to replace the lines but the values to replace are very specific. I'm basically entering the string to look for to replace.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#replacement') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #replacement

CREATE TABLE #replacement (
   string_pattern VARCHAR(100),
   string_replacement VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO #replacement (
   string_pattern,
   string_replacement
)
VALUES
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model1" FullPath="Model1" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model2" FullPath="Model2" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model3" FullPath="Model3" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model4" FullPath="Model4" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model5" FullPath="Model5" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model6" FullPath="Model6" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model7" FullPath="Model7" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model8" FullPath="Model8" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model9" FullPath="Model9" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model10" FullPath="Model10" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model11" FullPath="Model11" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model12" FullPath="Model12" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model13" FullPath="Model13" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model14" FullPath="Model14" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model15" FullPath="Model15" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model16" FullPath="Model16" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model17" FullPath="Model17" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model18" FullPath="Model18" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model19" FullPath="Model19" ViewType="ModelView" />', ''),
   ('<SaveFileModel Header="Model20" FullPath="Model20" ViewType="ModelView" />', '');

DECLARE @string AS VARCHAR(MAX),
        @userident varchar(20);

DECLARE userviewdef CURSOR FOR
SELECT
        UserID
    FROM
        TableSettings where section = 'user view session'

OPEN userviewdef;

FETCH NEXT FROM userviewdef INTO
    @userident;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        select @string = varcharvalue from tablesettings where section = 'user view session' and userid = @userident

        -- Perform all replacements
        SELECT @string = REPLACE(@string, string_pattern, string_replacement) FROM #replacement;

        -- Return new string
        --PRINT @string;
        
        update tablesettings
        set varcharvalue = @string
        where section = 'user view session' and userid = @userident
        

        FETCH NEXT FROM userviewdef INTO
        @userident;

    END;

CLOSE userviewdef;

DEALLOCATE userviewdef;
```

There are instances where a string could be what is seen below and it would not get removed since it doesn't fit any of the strings I coded to be removed. I want to find an easy way to remove any lines where ViewType="ModelView" since this is my criteria.

```
<SaveFileModel Header="ThisIsSomethingElse" FullPath="Model1" ViewType="ModelView" />
```

4/21/21:
After following the advice of @FrankPl to use XML here is what I came up with. The result returns a blank space. I might be coding the XML query piece incorrectly and need a bit of help:

```
DECLARE @stringXML XML,
        @finalString varchar(max),
        @userident varchar(20);

        

DECLARE userviewdef CURSOR FOR

SELECT
        UserID
    FROM
        TableSettings where section = 'user view session';

OPEN userviewdef;

FETCH NEXT FROM userviewdef INTO
    @userident;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        select @stringXML = varcharvalue from tablesettings where section = 'user view session' and userid = @userident

        
        select @stringXML.query('
            for $item in (/SaveFileContext/Mappings/SaveFileModel)
            return if ($item[@ViewType = "ModelView"]) then string($item) else ""
            ')

        select @finalString = convert(varchar(max), @stringXML)

        -- Return new string
        PRINT @finalstring;
        

        FETCH NEXT FROM userviewdef INTO
        @userident;

    END;

CLOSE userviewdef;

DEALLOCATE userviewdef;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare your `@step` variable as data type `XML` instead of `varchar`, you can use XQuery to process the data, in this case [a FLOWR expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/xquery/flwor-statement-and-iteration-xquery) in curly braces within literal XML elements, the curly  braces switch from literal mode to XPath mode:

```
SELECT @string.query('
    <SaveFileContext>    
        <Mappings> {
   for $item in (/SaveFileContext/Mappings/SaveFileModel)  
   return if ($item[@ViewType = "ModelView"]) then $item else ()
      } </Mappings>  
   </SaveFileContext>
'
```

The XML declaration and the namespaces are swallowed by the SQLServer XML processor.

This solution assumes the data are valid XML fragments.

Please note that - as the whole query needs to be a SQL string (i. e.  in single quotes), and XQuery accepts strings in double as well as in single quotes, for simplicity, I used double quotes here. Alternatively, I could have used doubled single quotes to escape them within the SQL string.

Comment: @frankpi Genius! Thanks I will give this a shot tomorrow

Comment: @FrankPI - I can't seem to get it to work. I have updated my original post with the query I am using

Comment: @user3438211 You should use something like `set @finalString = convert(varchar(max), @stringXML.query('...'))`. The `query` method does not change the XML it operates on, but return the query result.

Comment: @FrankPI - so I made some progress but not quite there yet. Here is what I did: ```set @finalString = convert(varchar(max)), @stringXML.query('
            for $item in (/SaveFileContext/Mappings/SaveFileModel)
            return if ($item[@ViewType = "ModelView"]) then string($item) else ""
            '). ``` This got me to return an output of ```&#x20;``` which I'm not sure what this means

Comment: @user3438211 I corrected my code, we need t return XML, not strings here. Now it should work.

Comment: @FrankPI - awesome! We're getting somewhere! It's pulling back only records where ViewType = "modelview". Is there anyway we can pull back all other lines except where ViewType="modelview"?

Comment: @user3438211 Not sure I understand your requirement exxactly. If you want to return all elements except the ModelView ones then use `$item[@ViewType != "ModelView"]` instead of `$item[@ViewType = "ModelView"]`.

Comment: @FrankPI - I was hoping to return lines including <XML>, <SavefileContext>, and all element lines except for lines where ViewType="modelview". I think I can work with this though since it can identify exactly what I want to remove. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user3438211 I again edited the solution.

Comment: @FrankPI - you sir are a genius. I wish I could upvote you but I'm too new. Thanks for your help kind stranger!

Comment: @FrankPI - is there a way to search for an element with a wildcard? So for example if I wanted to search for ModelView% in: ```$item[@ViewType != "ModelView"]```

Comment: @user3438211 That would be a separate question on Stackoverflow. However, quick response: SQL Server does not support the full XQuery 2 syntax, which would have regular expressions which would among others allow something like wildcards. But SQL Server supports a subset of XPath 1. You can find a list of the functions supported at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-functions-against-the-xml-data-type, which among others comprise a `contains` function which might be what you need.

Comment: @FrankPI - thank you I will look into this